# Erro "invalid input '..' in utf8towcs" com o "read.csv"

Tags: utf-8, csv, r

Tenho um banco de dados em .csv que reúne postagens tanto do Facebook quanto do twitter.
Para a leitura do banco em R, o código que tenho usado é

```
 bancodedados <- read.csv("nomedobanco.csv", sep=";", encoding="UTF-8")
```

**O código carrega o banco de dados quase até o final, só que um erro interrompe a leitura:**

> invalid input 'RT @jmlara02: @LizCorreaa Camarada defina multicentrico camarada. ðŸ‘‰ @90Javier @NicolasMaduro' in 'utf8towcs'

Fazendo uma busca na internet, vi que o problema é, de certa forma, recorrente. Ele é causado pelo não reconhecimento de caracteres previsto no meu código (UTF-8), que, no caso, é "ðŸ‘‰".

**Algumas propostas de solução vista na internet:**

- Manualmente retirar os caracteres da base original._No caso, eu
  descartei essa hipótese porque o banco de dados é bem grande e a
  memória RAM do computador não tão grande.
- Usar a função tryCatch(), o "error handling" do R, ignorar esse
  erro e prosseguir com a leitura. Achei essa a melhor hipótese, só que
  o uso do código é bastante não amigável. Tentei o pacote "debug" do
  CRAN...também não achei muito melhor que o default.
- Carregar, através do pacote "tm" do CRAN para o VCorpus. Realmente consegui carregar o banco e dados por essa via, no entanto ele não veio no formato dataFrame, ou seja...era o ,csv puro ali.

**Portanto, a pergunta que fica é:**

Seria a solução 2 a melhor, mesmo? Caso sim, como implementar o tryCatch junto com o read.csv para ignorar o erro e finalizar a leitura do banco de dados?

Se alguém possuir um manual de "Error handling" em português pode ajudar, também, rs.

**Alguns links do problema :**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143270/read-umlaut-from-csv-file-in-rattle

http://minimalr.com/2013/01/06/tolower-error-catching-unmappable-characters/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637278/r-tm-package-invalid-input-in-utf8towcs

Comment: Essa questão de encoding sempre é complicada. Sem ver os dados é difícil dar uma resposta certa, mas provavelmente algo nas seguintes linhas funcionaria: (i) leia o csv usando `readLines()`. Isso vai gerar um grande objeto de texto no R. (ii) converta o texto para o encoding correto usando `iconv()`. (iii) converta para data.frame usando `read.table(text = objeto_que_voce_criou_com_readLines)`. Isso deve funcionar.

Comment: Tu já tentou salvar em .txt e carregar pro dataframe? Se lembre de colocar o enconding UTF-8. Forneça um pequeno exemplo do arquivo para poder repetir a situação.

Comment: Eric, a sugestão acima funcionou, você conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Eu costumo utilizar o `file.choose()` para eu mesmo selecionar o arquivo.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

dados = read.csv2(file.choose(), header = T)
print(dados)
```

O `read.csv2` já separa o csv em `";"` e o `T` ou `F` é para definir a "cabeça" do banco de dados.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

permita-me 'upar' o tópico com uma possível solução.

Tente o seguinte:

```
install.packages('stringr')
txt.tmp <- str_replace_all(conteudo_do_tweet,"[^[:graph:]]", " ")
```

A chamada acima remove os conteúdos gráficos existentes no tweet.

Comment: Jhonatas, sua resposta não resolve o problema diretamente porque o AP não conseguiu carregar os dados no R. Talvez seja uma solução em conjunto com a sugestão do Carlos nos comentários, mas a pergunta não pode ser testada sem um exemplo de dados reprodutível.

Comment: Hmmm, de fato. Entendi o que quis dizer. Poderia tentar essa solução na aplicação que gera o CSV, talvez. De qualquer forma, acho que o Eric desistiu ou ja encontrou a solução do problema.. hehe